# Communicate/transfer data between two different programs. JAVA & VERILOG

Tags: java, verilog, ipc, serial-communication, iverilog

I am building two programs that run independently of each other. I wish to make output of one program (JAVA) as input to another program (Verilog) and vice-versa.

I am building a calculator and have to do calculations in Verilog but UI in Java.
Both programs run on the same device.
Also how to invoke Verilog program when java program UI is invoked by the user???

I right now have no idea except for somehow making a pipe between two programs/read between ports or something or maybe make use of files to store and read data.

I don't know how to make named pipes in Verilog so please do tell. Also how shared memory can be achieved between JAVA and VERILOG is another thing.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean with "verilog program". For example, I used verilog to program an fpga, which was then running independently of the computer on which I wrote the verilog code. Indead, it is like you have a verilog program running on the same computer on which you have Java. Are you able to read a file from your "verilog program"?

Comment: I intend to get values like "2+2" from Java and then do the calculations in verilog program(adder). The output then needs to be given back to Java program. 
I am just doing this for my assignment and am very new to the field hence I don't know all concepts and terms.

Comment: Good, let us try to establish a communication protocol among us! I must understand where this verilog program is running. Typically, verilog is used for things that are totally different from normal programs running on a computer. Do you have an external device, where the verilog program will run? What is instead the computer where Java is running? A possibility is that you are "simulating" the execution of the verilog program on a computer. I ask because a verilog program is totally different from a Java program (or C, or python, etc.)